# How to check if Notepad++ is installed using Powershell

Tags: powershell

I am writing some powershell script to check if notepad++ is installed on my laptop. Though I'm having some issues with this.

**Here's the code:**

```
# Variable(s)

$regkey = "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Notepad++"
#
# Check if Notepad ++ is already installed.

If($regkey)
{
    Write-output "Notepad++ is already installed on your machine."
}
Else
{
    Write-Output "Notepad++ is not installed on your machine."
}
```

I uninstalled notepad++ manually. I then executed the script and the output message that was displayed was that notepad++ is installed, when it isn't. Why is this?

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
$w64=Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* | where-Object DisplayName -like 'NotePad++*'
$w32=Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*  | where-Object DisplayName -like 'NotePad++*'
if ($w64 -or $w32)
{
    Write-output "Notepad++ is already installed on your machine."
}
Else{
    Write-Output "Notepad++ is not installed on your machine."
}
```

Comment: Nice script +1, but there is a common misunderstanding. The output of `$w32.DisplayName` is here `Notepad++ (64-bit x64)` Wow64 means Windows on windows64 so 32Node is the 32bit subsystem.

Answer (score 0):

You never test if registry path exists.

`If($regkey){}` always returns `True` because the variable is not null so Notepad++ is always installed.

Try this, it checks if a registry path exists :

```
if(Test-Path "hklm:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Notepad++"){
    Write-output "Notepad++ is already installed on your machine."
}
Else{
    Write-Output "Notepad++ is not installed on your machine."
}
```

Comment: Hi, I just reinstalled notepad++ and executed your recommended script, it still prints out the incorrect output message, which in this case was that it's NOT installed, when it is.

Comment: Right now, notepad++ is installed on my machine, but when I run the script, the output shows as NOT installed.

Comment: Are you sure your Notepad++ is stored in Wow6432Node? Mine is stored in it and no problem, it says "Installed"

Comment: Yep, I'm looking at it right now, its in "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Notepad++ - Is it possible that it could be stored elsewhere?

Comment: Just test this code and tell me the error : `Test-Path "hklm:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Notepad++"`. Mine returns `True`

Comment: Mine returns as false.

Comment: And if you try this? `Test-Path "hklm:\SOFTWARE\Notepad++"`

Comment: Shows as false.

Comment: I tried this Test-Path "C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe" and it shows true.

Comment: Do you see a result with this? `Get-WmiObject -Class win32_product -Filter "Name='Notepad++'"`